# Unlisting a data frame by changing column names of the data frames

Tags: r

Let I have a list(list1) which consists data frames(df1,df2,..,dfn):

Each data frame consist different number of columns. As an example

```
list1[[1]]=df1
```

where df1:

```
x       y
----   -----
45     6
65     87
12     90
```

and

```
list1[[2]]=df2
```

where df2:

```
a       b      c
----   ----    ----
23     67      43
71     13      8
2      9       12
```

I want to unlist list1 as returns df1 and df2

df1:

```
a1     a2
----   -----
45     6
65     87
12     90
```

df2:

```
b1     b2      b3
----   ----    ----
23     67      43
71     13      8
2      9       12
```

Namely,

- first data frame(df1) will headers as a1,a2,a3.....
- second data frame(df2) will headers as b1,b2,b3.....
- third data frame(df3) will headers as c1,c2,c3.....

and goes on.

How can I do that in R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you not want to keep them in a list? Look at `list2env` and `setNames` for what it sounds like you're asking for.

Comment: @A Handcart And Mohair, Since I will export each data frame as excel file, I want to unlist them.

Comment: You can use `lapply` instead of creating a lot of objects in your workspace. Anyway, `list2env` will do what you are calling an "unlist" activity.

Comment: As you told, I can use lapply for exporting the elements of list. However I can't rename the column names.

Comment: Sure you can. That's why I suggested `setNames`.

Comment: For a specific data frame, I can do it by the code: setNames(df1, paste("a",1:ncol(df1))). However, I cant do it for each element of list1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a mockup of what I was describing in the comments. I'm not showing `list2env` because that seems unnecessary to your end goal.

Sample data:

```
myList <- replicate(10, data.frame(v1 = 1:2, v2 = 3:4), FALSE)
```

Renaming columns and writing the data to csv files:

```
lapply(seq_along(myList), function(x) {
  FileName <- sprintf("%s.csv", letters[x])
  write.csv(setNames(myList[[x]], paste0(letters[x], 1:length(myList[[x]]))), 
            file = FileName, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

The result would be 10 csv files, named `a.csv`, `b.csv`, and so on, wherein `a.csv` will have columns named "a1" ... "an".

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can rename columns for data frames in a list using a loop.

```
for (i in seq_along(list1)) {
    setNames(list1[[i]], paste0(letters[i], seq_along(list1[[i]])))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot @A Handcraft And Mohair and @Gregor for your time. With suggestions of @A Handcraft And Mohair, my code is as below:

```
list2<-list()
for(i in seq_along(list1))
  {
list2[[i]]<-setNames(list1[[i]], paste(letters[[i]],1:ncol(list1[[i]])))
}
```